# MVC5 EF6 Read data from a database table without using model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC5 and Entity Framework. 
Scenario is this

1. I have to read from a already existing database
2. Only SELECT statements are used to fetch data.
3. This is shown as tables/reports in View

I don't need a model, Since the database is already designed and populated with data. I only need to use the SELECT statement to Query and show data.
A model requires KEY which is not needed in my scenario.

Can I create DBContext and use the context in controller to read the data to list and show in View

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest you learn a bit more about how EF works. You don't HAVE to query using the ID. You can perform any sort of lookup using LINQ.

Comment: Why do you want to use `EF` in this fashion seems like you would be just as well off using anything else

Comment: The whole point is having a model. If you think you do not need a model then EF (which is an O/R mapper) is not necessary, just use ADO.NET (not recommended)

Comment: I have already built an application in EF6 with MVC5 and Just want to show some data from an external database. So I won't be needing a model and only a controller with data context. So Just I want to know whether this is possible. I am basically a PHP developer. In cakephp this is possible by providing the data source as array in model and write custom SQL queries by over riding the Model pagination function. So once again let me rephrase the question. Is it possible to write a controller without model and use it to query the database with a dbcontext in MVC5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC stands for (Model View Controller) with separation of concerns for data.

**Model:**

An MVC model contains all of your application logic that is not contained in a view or a controller. The model should contain all of your application business logic, validation logic, and database access logic. For example, if you are using the Microsoft Entity Framework to access your database, then you would create your Entity Framework classes (your .edmx file) in the Models folder.

A view should contain only logic related to generating the user interface. A controller should only contain the bare minimum of logic required to return the right view or redirect the user to another action (flow control). Everything else should be contained in the model.

In general, you should strive for fat models and skinny controllers. Your controller methods should contain only a few lines of code. If a controller action gets too fat, then you should consider moving the logic out to a new class in the Models folder.

**VIEW:**

The two controller actions exposed by the HomeController class, Index() and About(), both return a view. A view contains the HTML markup and content that is sent to the browser. A view is the equivalent of a page when working with an ASP.NET MVC application.

You must create your views in the right location. The HomeController.Index() action returns a view located at the following path:

\Views\Home\Index.aspx

The HomeController.About() action returns a view located at the following path:

\Views\Home\About.aspx

In general, if you want to return a view for a controller action, then you need to create a subfolder in the Views folder with the same name as your controller. Within the subfolder, you must create an .aspx file with the same name as the controller action.

**CONTROLLER:**

A controller is responsible for controlling the way that a user interacts with an MVC application. A controller contains the flow control logic for an ASP.NET MVC application. A controller determines what response to send back to a user when a user makes a browser request.

A controller is just a class (for example, a Visual Basic or C# class). The sample ASP.NET MVC application includes a controller named HomeController.cs located in the Controllers folder. The content of the HomeController.cs file is reproduced in Listing 2.

Here is a good Video about Understanding MVC. http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/understanding-models-views-and-controllers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already built the application using MVC Pattern in VS 2013 with Identity 2.0 and Code First. and also I am clear about MVC Pattern. The scenario requires that I have to fetch data from  an external database of another application. I require only to retrieve data and show it in view. There is nothing more than that (no create update or delete). It will become very complex and time consuming, also unnecessary, if I write a model as this requires joins of more than 10 tables, SP's and DB Views while my requirement is only few select queries.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, Maybe you can use ADO.NET for just that area, i know it can make it a little messy but here is a link that may help. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/building-Asp-Net-mvc-web-applications-using-ado-net-entity-data-model/.  or just use a Raw SQL Query. http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/01/12/native-sql-queries-in-entity-framework/

Comment: is it possible for you to use web-forms in your application. with the code behind you should be able to access any database you need. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Comment: I found the solution using SqlDataAdapter() and DataSet                      -- DataSet dsRecordSet = new DataSet(); sqlDap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn); sqlDap.Fill(dsRecordSet); return(dsRecordSet.Tables[0]);                                                                                 Another method is to use the DbDataReader